# Axios with TanstackQuery - AxiosResponse.data is undefined even though the response is successful

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm trying to create a custom service / hook in react.

I already have a working example that specific to one of the endpoints returned by the backend. I'm trying to create a generic version of it, but for whatever reason the `data` attribute of the axios response is undefined.

Here is the code:

```
const fetchDataService = <T>(key: string, url: string, enabled: boolean): Service<T> => {

    const [result, setResult] = useState<Service<T>>({ status: ServiceStatus.LOADING });

    const { apiBaseEndpoint } = useContext(ApiEndpointsContext);

    const query = useQuery({
        queryKey: [key],
        retry: false,
        enabled,
        staleTime: 1000 * 10,
        queryFn: async ({ signal }) => (
            await axios.get<T>(`${apiBaseEndpoint}${url}`, { signal })
        )
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (query.isLoading || query.isFetching) {
            return;
        }

        if (query.isError) {
            setResult({
                status: ServiceStatus.ERROR,
                error: query.error as Error
            });
            return;
        }

        const axiosResponse = query.data;
        if (axiosResponse === undefined || !axiosResponse) {
            console.log(axiosResponse);
            // This shouldn't happen, but if it does, we'll handle it gracefully
            setResult({
                status: ServiceStatus.ERROR,
                error: new Error('Unknown error occurred when fetching data')
            });
            return;
        }

        console.log(axiosResponse);

        // We can safely assume there is no error
        setResult({
            status: ServiceStatus.SUCCESS,
            payload: axiosResponse.data
        });
    }, [query.isFetching, query.isLoading, query.isError, query.data, query.error]);

    return result;
};
```

As mentioned I already have a working "ungeneric" version that works just fine and sets the proper data.

I cannot figure out why this is the case. Inspecting the network tab I can clearly see that the response returned the correct data.

Comment: I think you need to add `return` statement in the `queryFn` before `await axios.get<T>(apiBaseEndpoint + url, { signal })`

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. The arrow function is a single statement. If I were to wrap it with curly braces then I would need return.

Comment: My bad. Didn't see that it is wrapped in parenthesis and not in curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I had accidentally provided the same query-key as another query (actually the old query I was trying to refactor and replace with this hook).

Anyone else that faces this issue, make sure you don't have multiple queries with the same key!